# Do you have to pay for the Google Maps API in order to use lightning:map feature?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, google-map

My company has directly used the Google Maps API before and once we got above a certain number of API calls we had to start paying for the service. I've noticed that the `lightning:map` feature of Aura and Web Components uses the Google Maps API. Do you also have to pay for API calls when you use a `lightning:map` or is that just included as a feature as part of Salesforce?

This would be part of a managed packaged and that is sold on the App Exchange and so it would be prohibitive if we had to pay ever time a custom loaded a page with the `lightning:map`.

Comment: Judging by the combination of this [Salesforce Knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000320191&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) and [this Google article about API keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key), it's safe to say it's not free after a certain threshold of uses.